# JavaScript loader while updating multiple table rows content

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, promise

I would like to display loader during an operation that takes a while and hide after it is done. My code just loops through all table rows (about 2000) and update content in their cells.

The problem is that this loader display does call doesn't fire before the code execution, so it doesn't show loader.

```
$('#loader').fadeIn();

const $rows = $('.rows:checked');

for (let i = 0; i < $rows.length; ++i) {
  const id = $rows[i].dataset.productId;
  const $text = document.getElementById(`text-${id}`);
  const $value = document.getElementById(`value-${id}`);

  $value.textContent = value;
  $text.textContent = text;
}

return $('#loader').fadeOut();
```

I expect that the loader shows before the loop starts and will be hidden after loop finish.

Comment: Use the `window.onload` event  or `document.ready` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: I forgot to say that this function fires after clicking a button

Comment: you are using for loop that will freeze page. if you wrap loop in settimeout then it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you we're trying to return the loader when it finishes the operation or before. You could use promises to tell when the function finished to hide the loader. And wrap the loader in a function to display or hide it based on a true or false value.

Something like this.

```
function loader(show) {
    if (show) {
        // True, we show loader
        $('#loader').fadeIn();
    } else {
        // Was loader(false) we hide it
        $('#loader').fadeOut();
    }
}

function start() {
    loader(true); // Show loader
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < $rows.length; ++i) {
            const id = $rows[i].dataset.productId;
            const $text = document.getElementById(`text-${id}`);
            const $value = document.getElementById(`value-${id}`);

            $value.textContent = value;
            $text.textContent = text;
        }
      resolve() // Resolve
    })
}
// Run start() function then wait until it resolves(), finishes to do something
start().then(() => {
    // Our loop finished
    loader(false) // Hide loader
})
```

Would essentially be doing this

```js
function loader(b) {
   if (b) {
      console.log('Showing loader');
   } else {
      console.log('Hiding loader');
   }
}

function start() {
    loader(true);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         console.log('Start()');
         resolve();
         // We also could use reject() for error handling
    })
}

let start_button = document.getElementById('start_button');
start_button.onclick = function() {
    start().then(() => {
         console.log('Function resolved and finished');
         loader(false);
    }).catch((error) => {
         // If we use reject()
    })

}
```

```html
<button id="start_button">Start</button>
```